# How to add html/text into a zend form htmlTag?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to inset text into a html tag created using zend form.

This is my code below, excluding my actual form elements

> ```
>  $this->addElements(array(
>
>  // My other form elements
>
>        array(
>            'hidden',
>            'dummy',
>            array(
>                'required' => false,
>                'ignore' => true,
>                'autoInsertNotEmptyValidator' => false,
>                'decorators' => array(
>                    array(
>                        'HtmlTag', array(
>                            'tag'  => 'div',
>                            'id'   => 'DescCharsRemaining',
>                            'setValue' => '
>                                2000 Characters Remaining
>                            '
>                        )
>                    )
>                )
>            )
>        ),
>
>        // My other form elements
> ```

I would like to add some text similar to 'setValue' but inside HtmlTag instead of a html property of the HtmlTag.

The result I get,

```
 <div id="DescCharsRemaining" setvalue="2000 Characters Remaining"></div>
```

The result i want,

```
 <div id="DescCharsRemaining">2000 Characters Remaining</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Zend_Form_Element_Text` you can insert your own html/text inside the form quite simply by doing the following.

> ```
> $text = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('descCharsRemaining');
> $text->setValue("<p>2000 Characters Remaining</p>")
>      ->helper = 'formNote';
> ```

Then inserting the object into the `addElements` array

```
$this->addElements(array(

   // My other form elements

   $text,

   // My other form elements
```

**UPDATE:** I have discovered a more simplified way to do this by just including the following directly into the array

```
array(
  'note',
  'desc',
     array(
       'value' => '<p>2000 Characters Remaining</p>'
     ),
),
```

With the result being,

```
<dd id="descCharsRemaining-element">
  <p>2000 Characters Remaining</p>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

A div isn't a form element, I don't see how it will accept a value. To do this you can create a new zend_form element by extending zend_form_element, create a custom decorator and control how the element is rendered or write a view script to replace the decorator.